# What happens to the absorbed colour on an object?

Tags: optics, visible-light, atomic-physics

If white coloured light falls on an object, colours of certain wavelengths is absorbed and colour of certain wavelength is reflected. We see the object's colour as the reflected colour.

Then what happens to the absorbed light? Does it move electrons to upper orbit? Then the object should emit some light when they come to their natural state which doesn't happen because then we would also see the absorbed colour. So what really happens to the absorbed colour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to photons after they hit objects?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137293/)

Comment: it is basically absorbed by the cristal lattice and reemited in the infrared https://www.quora.com/When-light-gets-absorbed-into-a-material-where-does-the-light-go

Comment: see also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168684/where-do-photons-go-when-they-are-absorbed  and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314562/what-happens-to-the-energy-of-a-photon-after-it-is-absorbed?rq=1 among others.

Comment: @Bill N Your first question mainly concerns white colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then what happens to the absorbed light? Does it move electrons to upper orbit?

It depends on the material, various things can happen. For usual surfaces the energy of the absorbed photon cascades down to the emptied state, turning into infrared heat.

> Then the object should emit some light when they come to their natural state which doesn't happen because then we would also see the absorbed colour.

Have you heard of [luminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminescence), photoluminescence,  and [phosphorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence)?